# Winforms data binding a control to an element of an array at specific index

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I am attempting to create a databinding between a numericupdown and an array element. In my form I have tried creating the binding shown below, but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Binding:

```
nudTest.DataBindings.Add("Value", eac.ESettings.HsvArray[0], "", false,DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Array:

```
public class ESettings : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private int[] hsvArray = new int[6];

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

          [XmlIgnore]
    public bool PrgVarIsDirty
    {
        get { return prgVarIsDirty; }
        set
        {
            prgVarIsDirty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PrgVarIsDirty");
        }
    }

    public int[] HsvArray
    {
        get { return hsvArray; }
        set
        {
            if (value != hsvArray)
            {
                prgVarIsDirty = true;
                hsvArray = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("HsvArray");
            }

        }
    }


    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: WinForms does not support such data binding

Comment: Is there a different way I should be doing this or am I just out of luck?

Comment: When you want to bind a control to an element of an array, instead of trying to bind directly to the element, bind control to the array, and then set the Position of CurrencyManager to the index of that element in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to bind a control to an element of an array, instead of trying to bind directly to the element, bind control to the array, and then set the [`Position`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager.position(v=vs.110).aspx) of [`CurrencyManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager(v=vs.110).aspx) to the index of that element in the array.

For example, below code binds the `NumericUpDown` to array and shows `30`, the element at index 2:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.numericUpDown1.DataBindings.Add("Value", array, "");
    ((BindingManagerBase)this.numericUpDown1.BindingContext[array]).Position = 2;
}
```

The same binding could be done using `BindingSource`. It's enough to set `array` as `DataSource` of the binding source and use the binding source for data binding. Then to show a specific element, set `Position` of `BindingSource`.

Comment: This doesn't work great if the model object should be supplied from another BindingSource, for example to display array elements in multiple columns of a DataGridView, where each array is a DataGridView row.

Comment: @BenVoigt The example above is a workaround for special case: "Data binding a control to an element of an array at specific index".  DataGridView supports complex databinding. As an example example, assuming you have a list of categories, each of which has a list of products and you want to show list of products in a DataGridView, for the selected category, then it's enough to use two binding sources, one for categories and another one for the relation/navigation property.

Comment: For more complex situation, if databinding doesn't work easily, you can define a custom type descriptor. For example, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65794579/transposed-editable-datagridview or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65925733/datagridview-databinding-to-listlistt  The examples are not relevant to this question, but they show how can you use power of type descriptor for databinding.

Comment: Yeah that's the path I am planning to go down.  It's a little complicated by the fact that I can't just associate a PropertyDescriptor with the DataGridView column, the column requires a `DataMember` string and insists on looking up that string with a type descriptor.  Wish the architects would have made extending it in this way a bit easier.

Comment: My particular case is that the user can define new columns via a configuration file.  The data for the custom columns is in a Dictionary on the data class.  I could build the grid contents without databinding but then I'd lose automatic refresh of changes to the predefined properties.  For simplicity, consider one predefined column "Status" and multiple custom columns.  The Status value will change many times while the row is displayed, none of the other predefined or custom columns will change after the row is added.

Comment: @BenVoigt Something like "DisplayMember" usually belongs to the editor (the column type, something like DataGridViewComboBoxCoumn). On the other hand, responsibility of TypeDescriptor, is flattening your complex model to a list of PropertyDescriptors which are responsible to get or set the value. In the property descriptor, you should not care about the editor/the column type.  I feel the examples that I shared could be of a bit of help. But anyhow, if you post a question including a simple [MCVE], I'll try to share my idea about it, if I have any.

Comment: "In the property descriptor, you should not care about the editor/the column type"  I agree.  But a more flexible design would be to be able to hand a PropertyDescriptor instance to the column type, and the string in the editor is just a convenience wrapper for setting the PropertyDescriptor.  Unfortunately in the current implementation of DataGridView the editor-friendly string is also the only programmatic interface as well.

Comment: @BenVoigt You have a full control on formatting and parsing of the value. You also know the data property name, you also know the data type, you also have the power of using type converters. I see all the Lego pieces here. It's just matter of what you want to build with them.