# Record columns to rows in grid C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

First off I'm not a programmer. I do know the basic stuff and have done website coding. This is quite a bit different obviously and it's something I haven't actually encountered before.

This might not be the place to ask this question, so please feel free to let me know.

Here's the link to SQL Fiddle that I created with a "sample" of the table. Obviously I've left out many columns because there is quite a lot of them. Balances etc and so forth for each account.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89db50/1/0

| AccNumber | AccDesc | BudgetThis01 | BudgetThis02 | BudgetThis03 | BudgetThis04 | BudgetThis05 | BudgetThis06 | BudgetThis07 | BudgetThis08 | BudgetThis09 | BudgetThis10 | BudgetThis11 | BudgetThis12 | BudgetThis13 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000000 | Test Account | 15 | 0 | 20 | 19.5 | 0 | 14 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I'm creating an app using C# and Winforms. I'd like to display a gridview where the table columns are "unpivoted" to rows. Since there is additional columns to my example that's not included, I need to be able to specify the table column names since I don't need ALL the columns in the table to be rows. Creating a view works but the problem with that is that I need to be able to edit the unpivoted columns data and update it in the example table.

What I need the grid to look like:

| Per | Budget This Year | Other Columns to follow |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BudgetThis01 | 0.00 |
| 2 | BudgetThis02 | 0.00 |
| 3 | BudgetThis03 | 0.00 |
| 4 | BudgetThis04 | 0.00 |
| 5 | BudgetThis05 | 0.00 |
| 6 | BudgetThis06 | 0.00 |

I'm truly lost with how to achieve this in the best way.

Your guidance in the right direction would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: can't use select query? like `select col1, col2, col3`...only fetch the required columns? and when modified then an update query only for those columns like `update <tableName> set col1 = x where id = n`

Comment: Hi Vivek. Thanks for the reply. Maybe I'm not understanding what you mean but I need these columns to be on a grid per line. I'll update my question and put an example of what I need it to look like. My apologies.

Comment: Not the easiest solution, but interesting: [Transposed editable DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65794579/3110834)

Comment: Thanks Reza. Looks promising. I'll have a look and see if I understand it all. :D If I have questions I'll shout.