# DataGrid-like Control that supports vertical columns, with fixed headers?

Tags: datagrid

This question has been asked before over the years, but the solution proposed to just flip the dataset does not address the issue with the column headers not being fixed. Consequently, when scrolling, the headers disappear to the left. The real solution should be implemented in the control itself. So either I find a control that offers that or I will have to code the whole control myself. I'm wondering if that control already exist. Side note : I need this control to work smoothly with many records.

Comment: Old question; but if you are still interested to an answer for yourself or future readerd: An illustration may help. Are you looking for something like this? [Transposed editable DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65797784/3110834)

Comment: You may also want to share the solution that you used for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to create a brand new control that implement the grid from scratch, using gdi+ to draw the cells. Much more flexible and also waaaay faster rendering. Implementation is still on the way.