# DataGridView Databinding to List<List<T>>

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

Given the code

```
class Foo {
    public string Value {get; set;}
    public int Id {get; set;}
}
List<List<Foo>> fooList = new List<List<Foo>>();
```

Is there a way to bind a Multidim ICollection to a DataGridView on the property Value, where when you change a cell, the Value property of the object updates?

In this case, each instance of Foo in the list will represent one cell in the DataGridView and the rows/ columns are being preserved as they would be in the multidim ICollection

By Multidim I mean something to the affect of:

```
List<List<Foo>] => [
    List<Foo> => [0,1,2,3,4,5]
    List<Foo> => [0,1,2,3,4,5]
    List<Foo> => [0,1,2,3,4,5]
    List<Foo> => [0,1,2,3,4,5]
]
```

Where each element in the nested list is actually and instance of Foo.

Comment: Flatten out with SelectMany : fooList.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng Would that preserve the rows/ columns of the multi dim array?

Comment: What do you mean by _multidim array_? An array of Rank > 1, like a `Foo[,]`? An array of Foo arrays, like `Foo[][]`, or, like you show, a list of lists (without an array in sight)?

Comment: Consider this… Since you want to bind a `List<List<Foo>>` to the grid, then each column in the grid would be a `List<Foo>` and since each `List<Foo>` could have a different number of `Foo`s in each list, then each column could have a different number of rows. Even if you “flatten” each `List<Foo>` list, using a `List<List<Foo>>` will just end up with ONE (1) column such that each row has a different number of `Foo` items in each cell.

Comment: I suppose multidim ICollection would be the proper way to put it. But yes, a collection of collections of a type. Think rows -> columns. Each list of lists is a row, then each object in the nested list is a cell in that row. @Flydog57

Comment: And, can you describe how the binding would work. If it's a list off lists, do the members of the inner lists represent cells, while each inner list instance represents a row? How are the columns defined? What happens if the inner lists are not the same length?

Comment: The columns are defined manually, the data in the list of lists is normalized before hand to ensure that there arent any rows longer than the others. Essentially what I'm wanting is to edit a cell in the datagridview and then have a property on the underlying object change. Similar to how ComboBoxes have  a "DisplayMember" property. @Flydog57

Comment: What columns are manually defined in the grid? How are you calculating the number of columns to create? I would think at a minimum, there would be at least `fooList.Count` number of columns. And the number of rows in each column would be the number of `Foo`’s in that `List<Foo>.` I am not understanding “what” columns would be manually defined in the grid?

Comment: The columns are just arbitrary, at the minimum there are `fooList[0].Count` columns. The data itself is arbitrary too. Very similar to how a plain old excel spreadsheet works. There is a displayed value, but there is also an underlying object that stores other properties that relate directly to the cell. And the size of the grid in excel is arbitrary. Thats essentially what im going for. Thanks for the input btw! @JohnG

Comment: You are missing the fact that `fooList[0]` is a `List<Foo>.` The grid isn’t going to know how to put a `List<Foo>` into a single cell. The same would apply for each of the columns `fooList[1]`, `fooList[2]` etc. I suggest you look at a Master-Detail scenario using two grids.

Comment: @JohnG Right. It shouldnt go into a single cell, but it should define the row, where the actual Foo object is the cell. This is all hypothetical, as i have no idea if .net has a built in way of doing this. Each List<Foo> should be another row on the table, where each Foo should be a cell in that row.

Comment: Just to clarify: you have a list (outerList) of lists (innerLists) of Foo. Each innerList has the same Count. Each innerList represents a single row in the grid. Each element in an innerList represents a single cell. Each of those elements is a Foo instance. Foo instances have two properties (`Value` and `id`). You want the cell to be bound to the `Value` property. Oh, and you want two-way binding. Do I have that right? If so, I don't have a clue

Comment: @Flydog57 Exactly. And unfortunate haha

Comment: You should really tag your question with `winforms` and `datagridview`.  Since there's a tag for `datagridview`, there's a chance that there are folks who are experts in this.

Comment: The easiest way is converting your collection to DataTable, edit in DataGridView and then convert it back to your object type. Another (harder) way of doing this is using type description API, something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65797784/3110834).

Comment: I also assume you will have Properties in your class, not fields. Having properties is necessary for data-binding.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Correct on the second one, I was using the term interchangeably but I'll redo the question with properties instead. The issue with the linked answer is that it only handles List's of objects. Not List's of List's of objects. I've done normal databinding to lists of objects. This one is just one level deeper than that.

Comment: Well, the linked post is not a duplicate :) I just shared it to give you some idea about type descriptor api and its power. Nothing stops you to create a view model for editing and then converting back data to the original model after the edit is done.

Comment: Which property of the foo is expected to be editable in DataGridView? Just one property?

Comment: @RezaAghaei No i get it totally. i appreciate the input. And yes just one property. I know the Columns have a DataBoundProperty field (or something similar) but i dont think that does exactly what im needing here

Comment: Yes.  I think this is better :  fooList.Select(x => x.SelectMany(y => y)).ToList();  You have an array X x Y x Z.  The select many reduces by one level to XY x Z

Comment: @jdweng I didn't see your comment and have posted an answer for flattening the list. If you would like to post your comment as an answer, let me know and I'll remove my answer.

Comment: It may look a bit strange that I've posted 3 different answers for this questions. But IMO the solutions are quite different and each of those have their points and putting them together in a single post make them less readable and less useful for future readers. Most of the users don't read very long posts. Hope future readers find them useful.

Comment: Bob, Did you find any of the suggestions acceptable? or let me know if you have any problem in applying the solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Implementing IListSource and mapping to DataTabe internally

You can create a custom data source which implements [IListSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.ilistsource?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and set it as data source of DataGridView.  To implement the interface properly to satisfy your requirement:

- In constructor, accept original list and map it to a `DataTable`.
- Subscribe to [`ListChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.listchanged?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) event of the `DefaultView` property of you data table and apply changes to your original list.
- For `GetList` method, return the mapped data table.

Then when you bind DataGridView to your new data source, all the editing operations will immediately reflect in your original list:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = new FooDataSource(yourListOfListOfFoo);
```

**ListListDataSource Implementation**

```
public class ListListDataSource<T> : IListSource
{
    List<List<T>> data;
    DataTable table;
    public ListListDataSource(List<List<T>> list)
    {
        this.data = list;
        table = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.First().Count(); i++)
        {
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T)).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
                .Where(p => p.IsBrowsable).ToList().ForEach(p =>
                {
                    if (p.IsBrowsable)
                    {
                        var c = new DataColumn($"[{i}].{p.Name}", p.PropertyType);
                        c.ReadOnly = p.IsReadOnly;
                        table.Columns.Add(c);
                    }
                });
        }
        foreach (var innerList in list)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(innerList.SelectMany(
                x => TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T)).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
                .Where(p => p.IsBrowsable).Select(p => p.GetValue(x))).ToArray());
        }
        table.DefaultView.AllowDelete = false;
        table.DefaultView.AllowNew = false;
        table.DefaultView.ListChanged += DefaultView_ListChanged;
    }

    public bool ContainsListCollection => false;
    public IList GetList()
    {
        return table.DefaultView;
    }
    private void DefaultView_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ListChangedType != ListChangedType.ItemChanged)
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        var match = Regex.Match(e.PropertyDescriptor.Name, @"\[(\d+)\]\.(\w+)");
        var index = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
        var propertyName = match.Groups[2].Value;
        typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(data[e.NewIndex][index],
            table.Rows[e.NewIndex][e.PropertyDescriptor.Name]);
    }
}
```

Then bind your list to `DataGridView` like this:

```
List<List<Foo>> foos;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foos = new List<List<Foo>>{
        new List<Foo>(){
            new Foo() { Id=11, Value="11"}, new Foo() { Id = 12, Value = "12" }
        },
        new List<Foo>() {
            new Foo() { Id=21, Value="21"}, new Foo() { Id = 22, Value = "22" }
        },
    };
    dataGridView1.DataSource = new ListListDataSource<Foo>(foos);
}
```

[image]

And when you edit data in DataGridView, in fact you are editing the original list.

Also if you want to hide a property, it's as easy as adding `[Browsable(false)]` to the property:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I *think* this may be exactly what I need. I haven’t had a chance to test yet, but I will let you know. Thanks everyone for your time.

Comment: Don't miss my other answer.

Comment: will do. I’ll look into which may be the best for a given use case.

Comment: I'll edit this one as well. I've made it a generic solution, so you can use it for ant kind of List<List<T>>, not just for Foo.

Comment: Alright, I tested both answers and they both work. They are independent from your model and you can use them for edit any `List<List<T>>` in DataGridView.

Comment: I think the only thing im gonna have to modify is `p => p.IsBrowsable` because the displayed property should be defined in the constructor, like DisplayMember in a combo box.(Also i cant change the properties of the class, 3rd party code) But this is literally so awesome, it'll work perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can keep it or remove it. I'd keep it, because by default all the properties are browsable, unless you decorate them with `[Browsable(false)]`. If you didn't specified the browsable properties at your model level (by attribute) the next opportunity for you is setting up `DataGridView` to show or hide specific columns.

Comment: Oh i see that makes sense, i may just put an overloaded constructor in there then, where you can pass a specific property name. These objects have around 60 properties, so itd probably be better to hide them from the onset

Comment: Yes you can. You have this code as a start point and you know your requirements and you have got the idea of the data source class :)

Comment: I like both solutions (this IListSource + DataTable, and the other one, TypeDescriptor). But I feel this one is easier to maintain and extend in a less complex way, at least DataTable is a familiar object while TypeDescriptor and PropertyDescriptor are usually strangers (but they are very powerful in facing-off the object for DataGridView, PropertyGrid, Databinding or anything which cares about the type description api.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you describe can be solved a couple of different ways. One is to “flatten” each `List<Foo>.` Basically this will flatten ALL the `Foo` items in a list into a “single” `string.` With this approach as I commented, you would end up with one column and each row would be a “flattened” `List<Foo>.` Each cell may have a different number of `Foo` items in the string.

In this case and as others, this may not be the desired result. Since you have a `List` of `Lists`, then a “Master-Detail" approach using two (2) grids may make things easier. In this approach, the first grid (master) would have one (1) column and each row would be a `List<Foo>.` Since we already know the grid will not display this LIST into a single cell AND we don’t want to “flatten” the list, then this is where the second (detail) grid comes into play. The first grid displays all the lists of `Foo`, and whichever “row” is selected, the second grid (detail) will display all the `List<Foo>` items.

An example may work best to show what I mean. First, we need to make an additional class. Reason being that is if we use a `List<List<Foo>>` as a `DataSource` to the master grid, it will show something like…

[image]

As shown the two columns are going to be the `List` “Capacity” and “Count.” This may work; however, it may be confusing to the user. That is why we want this other class. It is a simple “wrapper” around the `List<Foo>` and to display this we will add a “Name” property to this class. This will be displayed in the master grid.

Given the current modified `Foo` class…

```
public class Foo {
  public string Value { get; set; }
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

This `FooList` class may look something like…

```
public class FooList {
  public string ListName { get; set; }
  public List<Foo> TheFooList { get; set; }
}
```

A `List<FooList>` would display something like…

[image]

Now, when the user “selects” a row in the first “Master” grid, the second “Detail" grid will display all the `Foo` items in that list. A full example is below. Drop two grids onto a form and copy the code below to follow.

To help, a method that returns a `List<Foo>` where there are a random number of `Foo` items in each list. This method may look something like below with the global `rand` `Random` variable to get a random number of `Foo` items to add to the list in addition to setting a random `Value` for each `Foo` object.

```
 Random rand = new Random();

private List<Foo> GettRandomNumberOfFooList() {
  int numberOfFoo = rand.Next(2, 20);
  List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>();
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFoo; i++) {
    fooList.Add(new Foo { Id = i, Value = rand.Next(1, 100).ToString() });
  }
  return fooList;
}
```

We can use this method to create a `List<FooList>` for testing. The master grids `DataSource` will be this list. Then, to determine which list to display in the details grid, we will simply use the selected `FooList.TheFooList` property.

Next, we need a trigger to know when to “change” the details data source. In this case I used the grids, `RowEnter` method to change the details grids data source.

Below is the code described above. The master grid will have 15 `FooList` items.

```
List<FooList> FooLists;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  FooLists = new List<FooList>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    FooLists.Add(new FooList { ListName = "Foo List " + (i + 1), TheFooList = GettRandomNumberOfFooList() });
  }
  dataGridView1.DataSource = FooLists;
  dataGridView2.DataSource = FooLists[0].TheFooList;
}


private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  dataGridView2.DataSource = FooLists[e.RowIndex].TheFooList;
}
```

This should produce something like...

[image]

Lastly, this is just an example and using a `BindingList/BindingSource` may make things easier. This is a very simple example of using a “Master-Detail” approach with a List of Lists.

Comment: Agree that this use case is exactly where `BindingSource` makes things so much easier.  I would say that's ideal, but this works.

Answer (score 1):

### Using Custom TypeDescriptor

An interesting approach is creating a new data source using a custom [TypeDescriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

Type descriptor provide information about type, including list of properties and getting and setting property values. DataTable also works the same way, to show list of columns in DataGridView, it returns a list of property descriptors containing properties per column.

Then when you bind DataGridView to your new data source, you are in fact editing the original list:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = new FooDataSource(yourListOfListOfFoo);
```

**ListListDataSource implementation using TypeDescriptor**

Here I've created a custom type descriptor for each inner list to treat is as a single object having a few properties. The properties are all properties of each element of the inner list and I've created a property descriptor for properties:

```
public class ListListDataSource<T> : List<FlatList>
{
    public ListListDataSource(List<List<T>> list)
    {
        this.AddRange(list.Select(x => 
            new FlatList(x.Cast<object>().ToList(), typeof(T))));
    }
}
public class FlatList : CustomTypeDescriptor
{
    private List<object> data;
    private Type type;
    public FlatList(List<object> data, Type type)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.type = type;
    }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        return this.GetProperties(new Attribute[] { });
    }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        var properties = new List<PropertyDescriptor>();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor p in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(type))
                properties.Add(new FlatListProperty(i, p));
        }
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(properties.ToArray());
    }
    public object this[int i]
    {
        get => data[i];
        set => data[i] = value;
    }
}
public class FlatListProperty : PropertyDescriptor
{
    int index;
    PropertyDescriptor originalProperty;
    public FlatListProperty(int index, PropertyDescriptor originalProperty)
        : base($"[{index}].{originalProperty.Name}",
                originalProperty.Attributes.Cast<Attribute>().ToArray())
    {
        this.index = index;
        this.originalProperty = originalProperty;
    }
    public override Type ComponentType => typeof(FlatList);
    public override bool IsReadOnly => false;
    public override Type PropertyType => originalProperty.PropertyType;
    public override bool CanResetValue(object component) => false;
    public override object GetValue(object component) =>
        originalProperty.GetValue(((FlatList)component)[index]);
    public override void ResetValue(object component) { }
    public override void SetValue(object component, object value) =>
        originalProperty.SetValue(((FlatList)component)[index], value);
    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component) => true;
}
```

To bind data:

```
List<List<Foo>> foos;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foos = new List<List<Foo>>{
        new List<Foo>(){
            new Foo() { Id=11, Value="11"}, new Foo() { Id = 12, Value = "12" }
        },
        new List<Foo>() {
            new Foo() { Id=21, Value="21"}, new Foo() { Id = 22, Value = "22" }
        },
    };
    dataGridView1.DataSource = new ListListDataSource<Foo>(foos);
}
```

[image]

And when you edit data in DataGridView, in fact you are editing the original list.

Also if you want to hide a property, it's as easy as adding `[Browsable(false)]` to the property:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Flattening the List<List<T>> into a List<T>

If showing data in a flattened structure for editing is acceptable, then you can use:

```
List<List<Foo>> foos;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foos = new List<List<Foo>>{
            new List<Foo>(){
                new Foo() { Id=11, Value="11"}, new Foo() { Id = 12, Value = "12" }
            },
            new List<Foo>() {
                new Foo() { Id=21, Value="21"}, new Foo() { Id = 22, Value = "22" }
            },
        };
    dataGridView1.DataSource = foos.SelectMany(x=>x).ToList();
}
```

And edit data in a flat list, like this:

[image]

When you edit each row, you are in fact editing the original list.

Comment: And finally if showing data in a flattened structure for editing is acceptable, you can use this.